# Cannot read property 'handleReset' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, formik

I am using useFormik hook in my react native project

So i try to initialize useFormik in my another component and then import it in my Signup page and use here.Here is the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import {
  signupValidationSchema,
} from "../../validationSchemas";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export const SignupFormik = () => {
  const formik=useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      type: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
    validationSchema: signupValidationSchema,
  });
  return formik
};
```

signup.js

```
import { SignupFormik } from "../../Tools";
import {Form} from 'formik'
export function Signup() {
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.activityIndicator.isLoading);
  return isLoading ? (
    <View style={activityIndicatorStyles.container}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View style={signupStyles.screen}>
      <Form>
        <View style={signupStyles.FormWrapper}>
          <TextInput
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            onChangeText={SignupFormik.handleChange}
            onBlur={SignupFormik.handleBlur}
            value={SignupFormik().values.firstName}
            style={signupStyles.TextInput}
          /> 
          <Button title="Submit" />
        </View>
      </Form>
    </View>
  );
}
```

So as soons as i import "FORM" from formik and use it i get an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleReset' of undefined
>
> This error is located at:
> in Form (at Signup.js:20)
>
> Warning: Formik context is undefined, please verify you are calling
> useFormikContext() as child of a  component.

Answer (score 14):

You need to decide if you use hook (`useFormik` <- that's the hook) or component (`<Form>` <- that's the component). Formik prepared both. Component `Form` wraps the `useFormik`, and it requires additional parameters. That's why you have the error.

In your case, the fastest solution would be to use the hook (`useFormik`), so you would have to remove:

```
import {Form} from 'formik' // <-- remove it
```

and replace `<Form>` with `<form>`

I noticed that it's more popular in the react world to use hooks instead of components (of course I mean your case)

Answer (score 2):

You have implemented `SignupFormik` as a function, and this function doesn't have `handleChange` or others methods that you use.
Actually what you probably want to implement is a custom hook:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import {
  signupValidationSchema,
} from "../../validationSchemas";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export const useSignupFormik = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      type: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
    validationSchema: signupValidationSchema,
  });

  return formik;
};
```

And then

```
import { useSignupFormik } from "../../Tools";
import {Form} from 'formik'
export function Signup() {
  const signupFormik = useSignupFormik()

  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.activityIndicator.isLoading);
  return isLoading ? (
    <View style={activityIndicatorStyles.container}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View style={signupStyles.screen}>
      <Form>
        <View style={signupStyles.FormWrapper}>
          <TextInput
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            onChangeText={signupFormik.handleChange}
            onBlur={signupFormik.handleBlur}
            value={signupFormik.values.firstName}
            style={signupStyles.TextInput}
          /> 
          <Button title="Submit" />
        </View>
      </Form>
    </View>
  );
}
```